# Line Won't Break In PHP

Tags: php

In the code below I have tried to use the `wordwrap` function to make a new line every 255 characters. This is to prevent a long text from going off the screen. Could any help me?

```
 <?php 
$get  = new mysqli('', '', '', '');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY id ASC";
$result = $get->query($sql);

    while($r = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<div class='chat'><p class='u'>" . $r['username'] . "</p><br /><br /><p class='m'>" . wordwrap($r['message'], 255, '<br />\n') . "</p></div><hr /><br /><br /><br />";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what your question is? You've said what you want to happen, and showed what you're using to try to achieve it, but you haven't said what is actually happening. Are you not getting the output you're expecting? Are there errors?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I want when the user types in 255 characters it breaks the text in order to prevent text running off the screen.

Comment: So what's happening instead?

Comment: @Don'tPanic It doesn't do anything. It was the same as not putting the `wordwrap`.

Comment: Depends on how many characters are in the said row, and possibly CSS rules. View HTML source to see what it reveals also.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hard to do that. It updates the messages every 2 seconds. And collapses the `div` so I can't see it.

Comment: then disable the js momentarily. If you can't because it's a live site, then make a copy and test it there. Someone just popped another answer down there also. However, you could disable JS on your end and see the source there.

Comment: You should be able to persist the server responses in your browser console.

Comment: @Fred-ii- This is what I got. `<div class="chat"><p class="u">Username</p><br><br><p class="m">kvlkdvkv;lkv;ldkvl;dkv;ldjvkdjvikdvjfdivjdfiovjiodfvjfivkvlkdvkv;lkv;ldkvl;dkv;ldjvkdjvikdvjfdivjdfiovjiodfvjfivkvlkdvkv;lkv;ldkvl;dkv;ldjvkdjvikdvjfdivjdfiovjiodfvjfivkvlkdvkv;lkv;ldkvl;dkv;ldjvkdjvikdvjfdivjdfiovjiodfvjfivkvlkdvkv;lkv;ldkvl;dkv;ldjvkdjv</p></div>` The bunch of random text was for a test.

Comment: @BoeNoe  this is sample code i used:- http://prntscr.com/cpe2al  and this is output on my screen:-http://prntscr.com/cpe1ps

Comment: I tested your code; no problems. So, something else is causing this. Again; view your HTML source some way and you'll see the `<br />`'s along with a printed `\n` that should be wrapped in double quotes in order not to see those. I'm kind of betting on other CSS rules that are probably overriding that.

Comment: Are you sure that is not breaking at 255 characters? It looks like might be (although I did not count all the characters in that image.)

Comment: @Don'tPanic When I even tested at 15 characters all my other text breaked. Just that one didn't break.

Comment: @Anant But I wanted it where every time the user types 255 characters onto a line it breaks it. Not just one time.

Comment: so after user write it. it will be submits first? isn't it? if yes then it will work every-time

Comment: If you have actual semi-colons as part of your strings, then those could be a factor in all of this and PHP is looking at those as "end of statement" characters.

Comment: @Anant Let's say a user types 510 characters into the text box. It will need to break 2 times. Because 510 / 255 = 2.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Those lines strings do have semi-colons. They would make sense. Given that all my other text breaks except that one.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `cut` parameter suggested in [the answer from Mark H.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39837659/2734189)?

Comment: Well, if there isn't a solution to be found with PHP because you need those semi-colons, you may have to resort to a CSS solution and apply it to the div or `<p>`.

Comment: it is. Check in my link:- it breaks into two lines

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well, I don't necessarily need those semi-colons. But what about a user includes a semi-colon?

Comment: @Anant What about it needs to break 3 or 4 or more times depending on the case?

Comment: there isn't anything you can do about that. Unless you were to replace those with another character before it goes in db.

Comment: @Fred-ii- With `str_replace`?

Comment: yepper @BoeNoe ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for your help!

Comment: @BoeNoe you're welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Set the fourth parameter of `wordwrap()` to `true` in order force a break for words longer than the specified number of characters:

```
wordwrap($r['message'], 255, "<br />\n", true);
```

Comment: Really seems like this might be the answer, considering [the sample text being used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39837266/line-wont-break-in-php?noredirect=1#comment66964777_39837266).

Answer (score 0):

For the \n to be converted correctly it needed to be in double quotes

```
wordwrap($r['message'], 20, "<br />\n");
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
  $str =$r['message'];
  echo wordwrap($str,15,"<br>\n");
```

The width is not done in characters

Comment: It kind of works. For some text it does and some text it does not.

Comment: What do you mean by "the width is not done in characters"? [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) says: _"Wraps a string to a given number of characters..."_ Maybe I misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: Specifies the maximum line width. Default is 75

Comment: But 75 what? 75 words? That would be quite a long line.

Comment: in cols (in average character width).